# Esquema de versionamento

Tags: .net, versionamento

Em .NET, as `assemblies` geradas possuem quatro números de versão. Já ouvi falar muito em versão maior e versão menor (*major version* e *minor version*), e que esses seriam os dois primeiros números. Já ouvi dizer que o terceiro seria número de "manutenção" e o quarto seria o de "revisão", mas também já ouvi (e encontrei na internet) menções ao terceiro número como sendo o número de *build*.

Qual é a forma "correta" de se interpretar os números? Ou há mais de um padrão? E quando cada número deve ser incrementado?

Comment: Já olhou no [http://semver.org/](http://semver.org/)

Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:

1 MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
2 MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
3 PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forma "correta" de fato não existe, mas existem algumas indicações da Microsoft.

A MSDN indica utilizar a seginte [forma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51ket42z(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<major version>.<minor version>.<build number>.<revision>
```

Seguindo o modelo:

- Major version: Número que representa o fluxo da sua aplicação, quando sua aplicação muda drasticamente o fluxo ou é reprojetada, incrementa essa versão.
- Minor version: Número que representa o incremento de melhorias e novas funcionalidades, incrementa quando é a aplicação é atualizada com uma nova funcionalidade.
- Build version: Número do Build de compilação, geralmente incrementado automaticamente pelo Visual Studio.
- Revision version: Número de BugFix, correções em geral, incrementa quando sua aplicação é atualizada por função de correções.

[image: Versões no Padrão Microsoft]

A exemplo do próprio Windows:

- Windows XP = 5.1.2600.3
- Windows Vista = 6.0.6001.1
- Windows Seven = 6.1.7601.1

Answer (score 1):

### De acordo com o [SEMVER](http://semver.org):

(em tradução livre)

Dado um número de versão MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, incremente:

**MAJOR** (Versão principal), quando você fizer mudanças na API que quebrem a retrocompatibilidade,

**MINOR** (Versão secundária), quando você adicionar a funcionalidade de uma forma compatível com versões anteriores, e, por fim,

**PATCH** (Versão do patch), quando você fizer correções *retrocompatíveis* (bugfixes).

**Labels** adicionais para prereleases e metadados de **Builds** estão disponíveis como extensões para o formato MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH.

---

OBS.:

> No **.NET**, por padrão é adotado o versionamento com 4 números, sendo o terceiro é o **Build**, e o quarto é o **Revision** Number.

Espero ter sido claro.
Se ficar alguma dúvida pode comentar aí embaixo ou dar uma olhada na especificação do SemVer.

Comment: Poderia fornecer uma referência pra esse informação na box, Alan?

Comment: Das definições do .Net ou SemVer?
Para o SemVer : http://semver.org
Para .NET : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51ket42z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: A box de "OBS", cara! =D

Comment: Corrigido, chefe.