# Por que algumas bibliotecas começam com a versão "0.6" ou "0.2" ao invés de utilizar "1.2" ou "1.6"?

Tags: versionamento

Bem, aqui no StackOverlow Pude aprender sobre Versionamento.

- [Quando incrementar a versão usando Semantic Versioning?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51817/quando-incrementar-a-vers%C3%A3o-usando-semantic-versioning?lq=1)
- [Esquema de versionamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7457/esquema-de-versionamento)

Consegui entender perfeitamente o esquema de versionamento, e como cada um dos "pontos" que separam os números das versões funcionam.

Percebi que várias bibliotecas (como as do Composer por exemplo), com o padrão `#.#.#`, e costuma-se versionar a partir de 1 geralmente. Ou seja, `1.0.0`.

Por exemplo:

```
"phplegends/pt-br-validator": "1.0.4",

"maatwebsite/excel" : "1.1.0",
```

Eu achava que trava-se de um padrão começar a numerar a versão (primeiro dígito) da biblioteca a partir de `1.0.0`. Porém vi bibliotecas que começam (o primeiro número) a partir de `0`.

Por exemplo, essa biblioteca do [Barryvdh/Laravel-DomPDF](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) está na versão `0.4.*`:

```
 "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.4.*",
```

Por que algumas bibliotecas fazem isso?

Quando a biblioteca começa com `0` ao invés de `1`, tem algum significado especial (como uma versão beta, por exemplo)?

Comment: Geralmente são versões pre-release, ou ainda não maduras o suficiente para serem consideradas um *release candidate*.

Comment: Gente, qual é o motivo dos negativos? Eu não estou entendendo. Por favor, demonstrem aqui. Gasto tempo para fazer as perguntas para tirar minhas dúvidas e as dúvidas de alguém, e vocês ficam aí fazendo isso. Se realmente tem algo errado, não fiquem calados, mostrem...

Comment: Obrigado pela informação @OnoSendai :D

Comment: Além do que o @OnoSendai existem alguns raros casos de releases que ficam no `0.x` devido ao desenvolvedor não entender bem como funciona versionamento.

Answer (score 7):

> Por que algumas bibliotecas fazem isso?

Porque as respectivas equipes de desenvolvimento não as consideram como estáveis. Há uma série de motivos para isso, como maturidade, tempo de uso, adesão de uma quantidade considerável de sistemas, e assim por diante.

> Quando a biblioteca começa com 0 ao invés de 1, tem algum significado especial (como uma versão beta, por exemplo)?

[Segundo o Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/), indicar um número de versão iniciado por 0 quer dizer que o desenvolvedor considera que a biblioteca em questão ainda está sendo desenvolvida, ganhando funcionalidades, etc., e que, portanto, ainda está num estágio *alpha* ou *beta*.

Comment: Apesar de tomar negativos (talvez por alguns pensarem que isso é óbvio), eu só conheço na prática o versionamento do `Composer`. E não entendo porque utilizam o `0.5`, já que isso significa `alpha` ou `beta`, uma vez que o ramo `master` geralmente trata-se da versão em desenvolvimento (geralmente chamada de `dev-master`)... Me corrija se eu estiver errado

Comment: Versionamento é uma coisa. O ramo principal ou ramo de desenvolvimento é outra, e não são correlacionados. A numeração da versão é um ponto de vista do desenvolvedor ou do time de desenvolvimento.

Comment: Valeu, filho...